# Async method in map Ts

Tags: typescript, asynchronous

This is how I call the method:

```
console.log( (a: User[]).map(e1 => (b: String[]).map(async e2 => await this.method(e1, e2))) );
```

And this is the method itself:

```
private method(u: User, s: string): Promise<string> {
    return await firstValueFrom(this.translate.get( (u.abcd(s): string) ));
}
```

Currently I get a `ZoneAwarePromise` How can I do to get the result without using a `then`?

Comment: Have you tried using `async/await` inside `.map()`? `console.log( (a: User[]).map(e1 => (b: String[]).map(async (e2) => await this.method(e1, e2))) );
`

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to set them in the post

Answer (score 1):

Since the call to `map()` returns an array of promises, `await Promise.all(promiseArray)` is the obvious choice.

Note though that this doesn't guarantee order of execution, which is usually fine for async code (after all, that's probably why the code is async in the first place).

If you need the async methods to be called in a specific order, you need to replace your `.map()` with a `for...of` loop and await for each call in the loop.

In either case, calling `await` in a mapping function does nothing, as the mapping function will still return a `Promise` (as it's been declared `async`).